# How to check if a symmetric random variables is the difference of two iid symmetric random variables

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions

I have the continuous symmetric random variable $X$ in $\mathbb{R}$. If I know its distribution function $F(x)$ what are the conditions on $F(x)$ so that $X=Y_1 - Y_2$ where $Y_i$ are also iid continuous symmetric random variables in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Can you give some examples and non-examples to help find reasonable conditions?

Comment: One obvious necessary condition is that the characteristic function (aka Fourier transform) $\int e^{itx} dF(x)$ must be nonnegative.

Comment: ... and (some branch of) its square root will then be the characteristic function of $Y_i$.  By Bochner's theorem you just have to check that this square root is positive definite.

Answer (score 1):

No conditions are necessary.
Let $Y_2$ be any continuous symmetric random variable independent of $X$.  Then $X + Y_2$ is a continuous symmetric random variable.

Perhaps you wanted $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ to be independent?